# Javascript function not being called by onclick event

Tags: javascript, jquery, razor

So, I have this link:

```
<li><a id='HomeLink' href="#" style="font-size:large" onclick="loadPartialHome();alert('huzza!');">Receitas</a></li>
```

And the corresponding function:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        function loadPartialHome() {
            $.get('@Url.Action("IndexPartial","Home")', function (data) {
                $('#partialLoader').html(data);
                $('#partialLoader').fadeIn();
            });
        }
    });
```

Why is it not working? If I take the function call off of the onclick event, the alert displays the message, but if the function is there, it doesnt get to it. I tried debugging it but it never reaches the controller. What is wrong with this code?

---

Just to be clear, I tried using global function and a proper event handler, and it didn't work.

Comment: Your function must be global. You've hidden it inside a function scope. There's no need to wait for the DOM to load just to create a function.

Comment: If a global function didn't work, then you have some other issue that's not represented in the code you provided. Given that you've made no mention of error messages, should we take that to mean your developer console is closed?

Comment: @squint - so now we find out that the solution in that duplicate does not fix the OP's issue - they obviously have something else wrong in their page.

Comment: I just paid attention to the console and it shows only this error:
Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery.
I went to look and saw that I'm not using the Jquery version that is declared on my code. Now it works. I apologize the lack of attention to this.

Comment: @jfriend00: It doesn't fix all that is wrong in the world. It only fixes that which was presented in the question.

Comment: @guilofrano: Glad you got it figured out.

Answer (score 0):

`loadPartialHome()` must be defined as a global variable in order to be reachable from your HTML.  Right now, it's defined inside your `$(document).ready()` and thus is ONLY available inside that scope.

You can literally just move the define outside of your `.ready()` handler because there's no need to wait for the DOM to be ready just to declare a javascript function:

```
function loadPartialHome() {
    $.get('@Url.Action("IndexPartial","Home")', function (data) {
        $('#partialLoader').html(data).fadeIn();
    });
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    // another other code here
});
```

---

Of course, a better practice would be to pratice ["unobtrusive javascript"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) and not define event handlers in your HTML at all, but to set up the event handler in your javascript and remove the `onlick="loadPartialHome"` from your HTML like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#HomeLink").click(function(e) {
        $.get('@Url.Action("IndexPartial","Home")', function (data) {
            $('#partialLoader').html(data).fadeIn();
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I've tried using an event an event handler and it also didn't work, and by global function, do you mean just take out the "$(document).ready" part, because I tried that as well, and it didn't work.

Comment: @guilofrano - My meaning is exactly shown in the code examples I have.  If you don't understand those code examples, please ask a more specific question about one of the code examples.  There is NO need to just declare a function inside of `$(document).ready()`.  You need `$(document).ready()` for code that wants to access the DOM upon page load and that code is located before the HTML of the document.  That's the only time you need it.  I used it in my second example because I'm attaching an event handler to an element in the DOM.  No need in the first example.

Comment: Hi, you could try an onclick function in your javascript page load - e.g.

    var homeLink= document.getElementById('HomeLink');
    homeLink.onclick = loadPartialHome();

Comment: @jfriend00 I tried both ways. None of them worked.

Comment: @guilofrano - then you have something else wrong in your page in addition.  Did you look in the debug console for script errors or loading errors?  Have you loaded jQuery into the page?